# Why does .each here result in the same value for each item in the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to build an array of hashes (called `hashes`) from a two dimensional array `guys`.

I have this:

```
guys = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
hash = { a: [], b: [] }
hashes = []

guys.each do |guy|
  hash[:a] = guy[0]
  hash[:b] = guy[1]
  hashes << hash
end

puts "#{hashes}"
```

This results in an array of like elements:

```
[{a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
```

I don't understand why this is the case. It seems to me that `<<` should append to the end of the list.

What I wanted is this:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]
```

Comment: guys is a two dimensional array. hash is a hash. hashes is an array of hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you append **the same** `hash` object to the `hashes` array multiple times. In the `each` loop you just *modify* the contents of that same hash, so the last modification will change *all* references to that hash.

To solve it, create a new hash object for each loop like so:

```
guys.each do |guy|
  hash = {a: guy[0], b: guy[1]}
  hashes << hash
end
```

Comment: I like this analogy: You are producing a play. You pick one actor, tell him "You're now Hamlet. Hamlet, stand here on the left." Then you pick the *same* actor, and tell him "You're now Claudius. Claudius, stand there on the right." then you turn around back to the left side, and ask in bewilderment, "Wait, where's my Hamlet?!?"

Comment: @Amadan: Brilliant analogy :-D ...haven't heard of that one until then. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, if I thought about it a bit more, I could make it more applicable - "Hamlet, take the Skull. Why the hell is Claudius also holding the skull?!?"

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving what you want. Not using `Array#each` though.

```
guys = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
hash = { a: [], b: [] }
guys.map { |e| { a: e[0], b: e[1] }  }
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>3, :b=>4}]
```

[Array#map](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) also executes the given block for each element of the array, but returns a new array whose values are the return values of each iteration of the block.